# Sorting list in LinkedList

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I have written this code to  insert and removing the element to and form the linkedlist. I want to insert elements into list in sorted list. How can I improve my "add" method to do this?

```
public void add(String element)
      {
       if (isEmpty()) 
          {
              first = new Node(element);
              last = first;
          }
          else
          {
              // Add to end of existing list
              last.next = new Node(element);
              last = last.next;
        }

      }

      /**
      * The toString method computes the string representation of the list.
      * 
      * @return The string form of the list.
      */
      public String toString()
      {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Use p to walk down the linked list
        Node p = first;
        while (p != null) {
          strBuilder.append("[" + p.value + "]");
          p = p.next;
        }
        return strBuilder.toString();
      }


           The remove method removes an element.
           @param element The element to remove.
           @return true if the remove succeeded, 
             false otherwise.


        public boolean remove(String element)
        {
           if (isEmpty()) 
               return false;      

           if (element.equals(first.value))
           {
              // Removal of first item in the list
              first = first.next;
              if (first == null)
                  last = null;       
              return true;
           }

          // Find the predecessor of the element to remove
          Node pred = first;
          while (pred.next != null && 
                 !pred.next.value.equals(element))
          {
              pred = pred.next;
          }

          // pred.next == null OR pred.next.value is element
          if (pred.next == null)
              return false;

          // pred.next.value  is element
          pred.next = pred.next.next;    

          // Check if pred is now last
          if (pred.next == null)
              last = pred;

          return true;       
        }
```

Comment: Just for clarity, are you asking how to add a node into the correct sorted order of your list? Also what is your class name?

Comment: If you have unique elements, use a `SortedSet`. It will maintain the correct order based on `equals()`.

Comment: What problems are you currently observing?

Comment: I just want to insert in sorted order.. there is no problem in this code @JasonC and Want toimplement remove method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sorted linked list. While insertion, we can make it insert at correct position.

1) if list is empty, make first and last as new element. else

2)if new element is less than first node, make new element as first. else

3) Iterate through the list, find a position where previous node is lesser and next node is greater or null. Insert the new node in this position

So using this method we can maintain the list sorted always.

```
 public void add(String element)
  {
      Node newNode = new Node(element);
      if (isEmpty()) 
      {
          first = newNode;
          last = newNode;
      }
      else if (element.compareTo(first.value) < 0)//if element is lesser than all elements in list
      {
         newNode.next = first;
         first= newNode;
      }
      else
      {
        Node after = first.next;
        Node before = first;
        while (after != null)// finding exact position to insert
        {
            if (element.compareTo(after.value) < 0)
                break;
            before = after;
            after = after.next;
        }
        // insert between before & after
        newNode.next = before.next;
        before.next = newNode;
      }

  }
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Sangeeth.. It is vaery usefull code for me.

Answer (score -1):

This should works:

```
public void addElementInSortOrder(final List<String> list, final String element) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        list.add(element);
    } else {
        // look for the correct index
        int index = list.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).compareTo(element) >= 0) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        list.add(index, element);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a useful answer if you could explain what the issues were in the OP's code, how you arrived at this solution, and why you did it this way. Code-only answers don't help anybody learn anything.